# What should I be using instead of `dig`?

Tags: network, macos, dns

I stopped using `nslookup` a decade ago because `dig` superseded it. Now I'm creating custom files in `/etc/resolver/` and finding that everything works... except `dig` (and nslookup).

Actually, **I'd prefer to fix dig** than to use something else. I write a lots of scripts that use those common tools. I don't like having to code 2 different solutions.

Comment: Local overrides bypass DNS resolution so you won't see that with DNS tools.

Comment: This works but is a pain to have to do `dig @$(awk '/nameserver/{print $2; exit}' /etc/resolver/ec2) prodmongo11.ec2`

Answer (score 3):

How about `host`?

The `host` command is very similar to `dig` except it's much more simple and doesn't have the very technical info (if you don't need it).  So, for example, a `host` lookup would look something as follows:

```
$ host apple.stackexchange.com

apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.129.69
apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.193.69
apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.65.69
apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.1.69
```

You can also specify which DNS server you want to use by adding it to the command:

```
$ host apple.stackexchange.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.193.69
apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.129.69
apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.1.69
apple.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.65.69
```

And if you absolutely need it, you can add `-a` to get the same output as a `dig` command:

```
$ host -a apple.stackexchange.com 8.8.8.8
Trying "apple.stackexchange.com"
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26262
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;apple.stackexchange.com.   IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
apple.stackexchange.com. 299    IN  A   151.101.129.69
apple.stackexchange.com. 299    IN  A   151.101.65.69
apple.stackexchange.com. 299    IN  A   151.101.193.69
apple.stackexchange.com. 299    IN  A   151.101.1.69

Received 105 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53 in 39 ms
```

Comment: `host` ignores `/etc/resolver` it's useless to me.